# No network in one of 8 rooms, although physical connection seems solid

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired-networking

In our house, I build the network myself: planning, laying the cables, patching everything up, WIFI APs, etc. It's about 10 wired ethernet ports from different rooms that all end up in one room where they go into a Netgear ProSafe 24-port Gigabit Ethernet Smart Switch. Everything works great for 5+ years and now I wanted to connect a computer in the last room that hasn't been tested so far.

No connection. I thought before I open up the sockets and re-patch this, I buy an ethernet tester and check where I screwed up. As it turns out, all my rooms including the one that doesn't work show correct wiring status like this

[image]

(It's an NF-488 cable tester for the interested)

However, when I connect a computer to that port, the ethernet doesn't connect, I don't see a light on the switch and, of course, I don't get an IP address.

**Question:** What would be a reasonable course of action? Is there a possibility that the physical connection is faulty even though the tester shows that all pins are connected correctly?

Comment: If a cable has been kinked, the tester may not give you the correct answer. String a length of cable through the house from panel to room. Does this work?  Probably. That tells you that you must re-run the cable to the non working room.

Comment: @John If you post your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it. Bought a server-rack with a new patch-panel, some keystone modules for easy wiring and now everything works :)

Comment: I have posted an answer for you.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, open up the jacks and double check for the correct color codes - split/mismatched pairs won't show up on the cable tester but they'll make your link fail.

Comment: @Zac67 The colors were all correct. I assume I just didn't patch one of the wires firmly or whatever. The keystone modules made that so much easier and I just repatched my whole network over the weekend. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a cable has been kinked, the tester may not give you the correct answer.

String a length of cable through the house from panel to room. Does this work? Probably. That tells you that you must re-run the cable to the non working room.  This will help you troubleshoot.

Also check rack connections as well.

See if this works for you.